# Firestore Document field reference

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to do a firestore field reference to a document i have created. However i keep running into this issue where i cannot refer the fields of the document, rather the id only. I have tried many solutions but come short. Can someone point out the issue that im having. Thank you

```
//Get single reference
exports.getSingle = (req, res) => {

    db.doc(`/single/${req.params.single}`).get()
        .then((doc) => {
            if(!doc.exists){
                return res.status(404).json({error:'Offer not found'})
        }
        singleData = doc.data();
        singleData.offerID = doc.id;

        return db.collection('comments').orderBy('createdAt', 'desc').where('singleID', '==', req.params.singleID).get();
```

The above code is a quick snapshot of my NodeJS back end. I want to refer the single field which comes from the request and check each document if they match and return all documents that match

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do isn't really possible.  You can only create references to a document, and you have to know the full path to that document.

If you want a value of a field in a document, you have to read the document entirely.

Comment: If you could accept this answer as correct, that will help close this question, as is customary on Stack Overflow.